# Addslashes not escaping properly

Tags: javascript, php, addslashes

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I have

```
$description = addslashes($description);
echo "<option onclick='updateTotals(`$urlOptions`,`$option_title`,`$description`)' value='".$description."' selected> ".$description."</option>";
```

An example of the text I'm trying to escape is

```
422458 - 120' Boom if NOZZLE BODIES is CR II single nozzle body
```

The source code shows the slashes added in, but the code isn't acknowledging the slash?

[image]

Comment: Can you use back ticks in HTML?

Comment: The back ticks seem to be working for options that don't have single or double quotes in their descriptions.

Comment: [`addslashes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes) was not designed to be used for HTML. Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to encode properly any dynamic value that you use to generate HTML. Or, even better, use a good templating system (it handles the escaping for you).

Comment: The backtick does not have any special meaning in HTML. It is a character like any other, no more special than `a` or `7`.

Comment: Apparently it's a JS thing for "template literals" aka interpolated strings. However, you should not be using these unless you explicitly want interpolation and are handling your data safely, otherwise it's another code injection vector.

Comment: If your purpose is to produce strings in a fragment of JavaScript code then you better use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: [How do you pass in a PHP variable into an inline javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19943367/2943403) and [escape all quotes and accents in php variable for javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56023393/2943403) and [How to send php variable onclick of button to javascript function as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44133675/2943403) and [Passing PHP Variable to Javascript Function (Specific code error)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13426609/2943403)

Comment: [PHP - Echoing a string as a parameter in a JavaScript onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67596261/2943403) and [How do I use PHP to encode a string containing quotes to make it safe for inline 'onclick'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43631023/2943403)

Comment: [Send multiple PHP variables to javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64773984/2943403)

Comment: Ah,  this (finally) looks like a good one: [Inserting a PHP variable in an HTML string being passed to JavaScript function via AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36340680/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to produce strings in a fragment of JavaScript code then you better use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). It escapes all characters that need to be escaped in JavaScript and also puts quotes around it producing a valid JavaScript string literal.

A short fragment of PHP code is better than any explanation:

```php
// a list of characters, including quotes
$value = implode('', ['a', "'", 'b', '"', 'c', "\n", 'd', "\\", 'e']);

echo("const value = " . json_encode($value) . ";\n");
```

Its output is:

```js
const value = "a'b\"c\nd\\e";
```

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/G5apY).

In fact, `json_encode()` is the best way to encode any data structure if your goal is to generate a fragment of JavaScript code.

Comment: It works for the double quotes, but I'm still having issues with the single quotes.

Comment: It works with everything because it generates JSON and any JSON is a valid fragment of JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase. I've added it in, the code is still having my original issue at the single quote in the 120'

Comment: Oh, I see it now. You don't generate some JavaScript in a `<script>` element but HTML. Apply `htmlspecialchars()` to the output of `json_encode()` to encode it properly as HTML. It won't look nice but it should work. Or, better, extract the JavaScript in a `<script>` tag and use [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach it to the HTML elements.

Comment: The output for the first suggestion came out like ```value='&quot;422458 - 120' Boom if NOZZLE BODIES is CR II single nozzle body&quot;'```

Comment: The code in the answer generates JavaScript to be used in `<script>` element. The text in a `<script>` element must not be encoded as HTML. The HTML parser does not care about it, it passes the text as-is to the JavaScript interpreter. The inline event handlers (`onclick="..."`) are, in fact, HTML attributes. They must follow the rules of HTML that say that some characters needs to be encoded in order to not be interpreted as HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

`$description` can broke your `option` in several ways. I's better to define a function to be called `onclick`, but going further, it's better to trigger the function `onchange` the select.

Take a look to this example:

```
<?php

$description3 = '<p>This is a single quote: \'</p>'; //Escape ' with \

$myOptions = array(
    'val1' => array(
        'text' => 'Option 1',
        'url' => 'https://url1.com',
        'title' => 'This is Option 1',
        'description' => '<p>This is description for <b>Option 1</b>.</p>',
    ),
    'val2' => array(
        'text' => 'Option 2',
        'url' => 'https://url2.com',
        'title' => 'This is Option 2',
        'description' => '<p>This is description for <b>Option 2</b>.</p>',
    ),
    'val3' => array(
        'text' => 'Option 3',
        'url' => 'https://url3.com',
        'title' => 'This is Option 3',
        'description' => $description3, //No need to escape anything
    ),
);

?>
<script>
var myOptions = <?php echo json_encode($myOptions); ?>;

function mySelectChanged(value)
{
    //Call your original function
    updateTotals(myOptions[value].url, myOptions[value].title, myOptions[value].description);
}
</script>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="mySelectChanged(this.value);">
<?php
foreach ($myOptions as $value=>$option) {
    printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $option['text']);
}
</select>
```

Comment: I will have to try this. Wouldn't the single quote in the description string mess up the array because it would end the description array value early?

Comment: @Nicole If description is in a variable, you don't need to escape single quote nor anything. But yes if you write a literal string, in that case, just use \. I edited my answer to show you both examples, look at `$description3` var.